# How do I flush rewrite rules

Tags: rewrite-rules

How can I flush rewrite rules after saving or updating any page? Pretty much a newbie and trying to figure out how this would work.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_save_post_function', 10, 3 );
function my_save_post_function( ) {
flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

Comment: Do not flush rules here. Have a read [this "usage" note](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules#Usage).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked much with `flush_rewrite_rules` function, but based on the [usage notes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules#Usage) mention by [nmr](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/147428/nmr) I think you could perhaps do something like this,

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_save_post_function' );
function my_save_post_function( $post_id ) {
  $maybe_some_extra_logic = true; // if applicable
  if ( $maybe_some_extra_logic && ! has_action( 'shutdown', 'my_flush_rewrite_rules' ) ) {
    add_action( 'shutdown', 'my_flush_rewrite_rules', 9999 ); // set suitable priority
  }
}

function my_flush_rewrite_rules() {
  flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```